# Jquery hide all apart from selected index from cached selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is hiding everything and not excluding the selected index.

```
this.showGroup = function(groupIndex) {

    var $groups = $("#products > li.group");    

    // Hide all groups apart from selected index
    $groups.not(groupIndex).find(".scroller").hide();

    // Show selected index
    $groups.eq(groupIndex).find(".scroller").slideDown();
```

I can't change the first line `$groups` because this is used further down my function and needs to select all of the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your HTML, you probably want

```
$groups.not(":eq("+groupIndex+")").find(".scroller").hide();
```

If you don't want to build a selector, you can use filter :

```
$groups.filter(function(i){return i!=groupIndex}).find(".scroller").hide();
```

Comment: The first example works, thanks. Didnt think I would need to create a selector to filter the index

Comment: You could also loop on them (directly or by passing a callback to filter). Selectors make a language that jQuery uses to search and filter (and sometimes jQuery needs to loop).